# How to Hide/show table div acting on keyup filter input case insensitive

Tags: jquery

I have a number of divs that are listed and I want to be able to add an input field that will allow a user to start typing and the divs are filtered accordinly

I'm trying the code below,

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        $('#filter').keyup(function()
        {
        var val = $.trim(this.value);
                var tr = $('#tagstable tbody td');
                el = tr.find('label:contains('+val+')').closest('td')
                tr.not(el).fadeOut();
                el.fadeIn();
        })
});
```

This code is not working irrespective of Case insensitive

http://jsfiddle.net/e08o7uct/10/

Comment: it is hiding the div what do you mean by not working?

Comment: I mean for example type  Five instead of five (Case sensitive)

Comment: try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e08o7uct/11/) i added `.toLowerCase()` and `change the event to on input` just to be sure you can add toLowerCase() to both the values

Comment: Thanks a lot .... this solved the issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#filter').on('input', function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.value).toLowerCase();
    var tr = $('#tagstable tbody td');
    el = tr.find('label:contains(' + val + ')').closest('td')
    tr.not(el).fadeOut();
    el.fadeIn();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="tagstable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label data-tagid="1" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline">
          <input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">hotel tag<span></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label data-tagid="2" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline">
          <input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">yoga tag<span></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label data-tagid="3" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline">
          <input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">jogging tag<span></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label data-tagid="4" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline">
          <input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">exercise tag<span></span>
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label data-tagid="5" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline">
          <input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">aerobic tag<span></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label data-tagid="6" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline">
          <input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">running tag<span></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label data-tagid="23" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline">
          <input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">Body Building<span></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label data-tagid="24" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline">
          <input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">BB<span></span>
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label data-tagid="25" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline">
          <input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">one<span></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label data-tagid="26" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline">
          <input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">two<span></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label data-tagid="27" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline">
          <input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">three<span></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label data-tagid="28" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline">
          <input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">four<span></span>
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label data-tagid="29" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline">
          <input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">five<span></span>
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input id="filter" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here...">
```

1. Added toLowerCase().
2. Change event to on input

Note:

to be safe use `toLowerCase()` to both values